# How to run external php script using Php shell_exec?

Tags: php, curl, exec, shell-exec

I have the following code on my index.php file. But it is not working properly.. When i directly visit domain.com/script.php  it works. I need this script to be executed in the background while accessing index page. Can anyone help me?

```
shell_exec('php script.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

Answer (score 0):

check php is running in safe mode or not shell_exec is disabled in safe mode for the sake of security why don't you use

> curl

to run the code

Comment: Is it possible to execute CURL post commands using shell_exec ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think there are 2 possible issues in your case

1) try this:

```
shell_exec("script.php 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &");
```

OR

```
shell_exec("script.php 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/mylog 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &");
```

2) A simple way to handle the problem of capturing stderr output when using shell-exec under windows is to call ob_start() before the command and ob_end_clean() afterwards

```
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of using shell_exec, you can make an ajax call to script.php when the user visits index.php.

Another option is to run the script.php as a cron job every 5 minutes or so. When the user visits index.php, some data can be saved to database indicating that script.php should run. script.php should check if it is marked for running.